# Xpath string incrementable with selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am having problems when making an XPATH chain incrementable with a for loop, it is returning errors and I don't know how to solve the problem.

```
for n_dato in range(2,101):

        name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="onu_configured_list"]/table/tbody/tr[' + n_dato + ']/td[3]').text;

        print(name)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`n_dato` is an integer. While concatenating you should type cast it to the string value.

You can try like below ways:

**1: Type casting**

```
'//*[@id="onu_configured_list"]/table/tbody/tr['+str(n_dato)+']/td[3]'
```

**2: Using `format()`**

```
'//*[@id="onu_configured_list"]/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[3]'.format(n_dato)
```

**3: `f string` in python**

```
f'//*[@id="onu_configured_list"]/table/tbody/tr[{n_dato}]/td[3]'
```

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fix the problem using Format this way you can make the XPATH incrementable

```
for n_dato in range(1,101):
        nombre = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
            '/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[3]'.format(n_dato)).text

        print(nombre)
```